# Create new df with each iteration of a for loop

Tags: r, function, for-loop, iterator

I have a function `tot_prof(number, df1, number, df2)` where the output is itself another df.

I am trying to iterate through `df3` to get the `string` values for the `tot_prof` function.

Each iteration should store the results of `tot_prof` as a new df (or all the results can be combine).

How can I do this?

I tried to create another function like so:

```
iterator <- function(df, cluster, prod_dat, q_dat) {

  l <- list(length(df))

  iter <- 1

  for (i in l){
    thisl <- i

    for (n in 1:nrow(df)) {
      prod <- n

      iter_out <- tot_prof(cluster, prod_dat, prod, q_dat)

      l[[iter]] <- data.frame(iter_out)
    }
    iter <- iter + 1
  }

  l <- as.data.frame(l)

  return(l)
}
```

It should return 310 observations for 10 different `prod` values - instead it returns 61 observations of the same `prod`.

I am very confused. Please help.

Comment: What about if you put `l` at the end.  You really don't seem to be returning anything.

Comment: @Elin please see my edits- you were right, I fixed that, but it still is not working properly.

Comment: Why are you making it a data frame? Start from seeing if it returns correctly as a list.  Then work on making the list into a data frame.

Comment: @Elin i took out the `as.data.frame()` and checked- the list is the same though, 61 observations of 1 product :s

Comment: *I am trying to iterate through df3* ... iterate by rows, by columns? Please post data and function's code, so entire script is runnable from an empty R environment (i.e., a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: Why do you have iter as the index?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not commenting (I am not allowed) but maybe a solution here:

For each `prod` you're saving a new data frame over the last one. A solution would be combining all `prod` data frame by columns (`cbind()`) or rows (`rbind()`). And at the end save it to the list `l`.

```
  iterator <- function(df, cluster, prod_dat, q_dat) {

    l <- list(length(df))

    for (i in l){
      iter <- i

      for (n in 1:nrow(df)) {
        prod <- n

        df <- tot_prof(cluster, prod_dat, prod, q_dat)

        if(prod == 1) {
          iter_out <- df
        }else {
          iter_out <- cbind(iter_out, df) # or rbind depending what you want 

        }          
      }
      l[[iter]] <- iter_out

      iter <- iter + 1
    }

    return(l)
  }
```